# Figma-linux has no permission to save or open file/folder

Tags: 18.04

When I want to save a file or get a file from Figma in Ubuntu 18.04.5 then a pop-up message appears saying no permission to open /folder.
The problem is not with the folder I guess it's with some kind of permission Figma don't have but I don't know what!

Comment: Can you save the file somewhere else? Creating `folder` in directory `/` requires write access to `/`, and is generally not done.

Comment: @waltinator folder structure is as it is in Ubuntu (Linux) I can't make a change to it. Currently, I am only able to save the file on the Desktop.